# Запятая после "мобудь"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Мобудь" — это синоним "может"? Если да, то требуется обособление, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю Ваши рассуждения верными и тоже написал бы с запятыми